# How to 2d array initial to 0

Tags: c++

```
int array2d[3][5]{};

for (auto& iter1 : array2d)
{
    cout << "iter1 in 2d array - " << iter1 << endl;
    for (auto& iter2 : iter1)
    {
        cout << "iter2 in 2d array - " << iter2 << endl;
    }
}
```

Result

> > iter1 in 2d array - 00CFFCB4
> >     iter2 in 2d array - 0
> >     iter2 in 2d array - 0
> >     iter2 in 2d array - 0
> >     iter2 in 2d array - 0
> >     iter2 in 2d array - 0
> >     iter1 in 2d array - 00CFFCC8
> >     iter2 in 2d array - 0
> >     iter2 in 2d array - 0
> >     iter2 in 2d array - 0
> >     iter2 in 2d array - 0
> >     iter2 in 2d array - 0
> >     iter1 in 2d array - 00CFFCDC
> >     iter2 in 2d array - 0
> >     iter2 in 2d array - 0
> >     iter2 in 2d array - 0
> >     iter2 in 2d array - 0
> >     iter2 in 2d array - 0

How to 2d array initial to 0??

Comment: it's already all zeros. those other values are addresses for each row (`iter1` is a reference to a 1-D array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your 2d array ***does*** have all elements initialized to zero! This is shown by the fact that there are ***fifteen*** lines in your output of the form `iter2 in 2d array - 0`.

The non-zero outputs for `iter1` are actually *addresses*: the type of `iter1` is `int (&iter1)[5]` - which is, for each outer loop, the address of each of the three 'rows' of the 2d array.

Answer (score 0):

for m rows and n columns,

```
vector<vector<int> > array2d( m , vector<int> (n));
```

Comment: this is both not an array and doesn't even guarantee zero initialization (since C++14)

Comment: @CruzJean I got confused with the term "2nd array" with "2d array",
by the way, what is second array? 

Comment: I think the "2nd array" thing was a confusion with what `iter1` is vs `iter2` in the question's code block

Comment: @CruzJean, what do you mean by "doesn't even guarantee zero initialization"? `std::vector<int>(n)` is a vector of `n` zero `int`s.

Comment: @Evg that constructor (since C++14) default constructs the elements. `int` default constructor does nothing, so not guaranteed to be zero. it's like if you just declared a variable `int val;` without giving it a value (uninitialized). If you want zeros, use e.g. `vector<int>(n, 0)`

Comment: @CruzJean Unfortunately, this is wrong. In C++11/14/17 you're guaranteed to get zeros. Since C++14 elements are ["default inserted"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/DefaultInsertable) instances of `T`. With a default allocator, elements will be [value-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/DefaultInsertable#Notes) as by `T()`. That is, `int()` for `int`.

Comment: @Evg Ah, I stand corrected. I was under the impression `int()` was uninitialized and `int{}` was zero initialized. Still, I'd recommend being explicit with the `vector<int>(n, 0)` constructor